# Adding .jar files with binaries(.sh file) in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar

i run the sensor analytics code in my pc vitual box. I need to run this code in another PC, so I copied binaries from my PC to another PC which is executing through the MXE200i board it is unable to run so I add .jar files also still unable to run.

I don't know where I made mistake please help me.

Comment: You want to do what??? This question is at least very confusing, and perhaps not about Java programming as such...

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question. Perhaps you should try [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) instead.